# What is the cleanest way to move confidential values from context.xml to separate file?

Tags: xml, tomcat, context.xml

Prefacing this with I'm not a java developer.

I have a context.xml file with various passwords and other credentials that need to be moved to another file. I've gotten this to work with entities but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this so only the specific value is loaded from the separate file instead of the entire resource or environment. For example, if I have

```
<Environment name="password" value="secretpassword" type="java.lang.String" override="false" />
```

I can replace the entire line by putting it in the 2nd file and loading it as an entity. Is there a way to do something like

```
<Environment name="password" value="$STOREDPASSWORD" type="java.lang.String" override="false" />
```

where the 2nd file has

```
STOREDPASSWORD=secretpassword
```

This info needs to be portable in a new file so I'm not able to put this in catalina.properties. I don't want to make any app changes; only config file includes or substitutions.

Comment: See the [FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=103099026)

Comment: Lots of stuff there but I don't see anything relevant.

Comment: Oops, somehow only half the link made it in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=103099026#content/view/103099026

Comment: Thanks. I've read all of that and have used entities to replace entire lines as stated above. I was wondering if there was a way to do just a variable substitution, without using catalina.properties. If not I'll continue to use entities but it would be cleaner for my purpose if I could just have something similar to a catalina.properties file but in a different, configurable file. The config file is secure but sometimes we have to give the contents to a developer and we don't want to mistakenly give them production db and other credentials by mistake.